# My R plots with the first 2 rows being equal begin from different start points. How do I rectify this?

Tags: r, plot, quandl

I have pulled some normalised stock price data from Quandl into R. When I check the first row for the close price of both stocks, they are both 100. However, my plot shows me a different picture.

My formula is:

```
plot(STC[,1],STC[,2], "l", main = "Lupin & Dr.Reddy", xlab = "Time", 
ylab = "Price", col = "green" )
par(new = TRUE)
plot(STC[,1],STC[,3], "l", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = 
"", col = "blue")
legend("topleft", c("Lupin", "Dr.Reddy"),
col = c("green","blue"), lty = c(1, 1))
```

The first Close price for both stocks is 100.

And my plot looks like this:
[The line chart from Dr.Reddy begins around 120](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GvIt.png)

Comment: you need to set the ylim of both plots to ensure they are the same.

Comment: or replace the second call to `plot` with `lines(STC[,1],STC[,3], col = 'blue')`

Comment: @RichardTelford I am reading up on the ylim function now. I am finding it a bit difficult getting acquainted with R after using only Excel for very long. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: ylim is an argument to plot (the function ylim() is in ggplot and won't help), but `lines` is a better solution anyway.